# Photorealistic Rendering of 3D shapes Dynamically

Tags: python-3.x, unity-game-engine, server-side-rendering, pythreejs

I need some suggestion. I want a tool in which I can get Realistic Looking images of My 3D shapes.
All 3D shapes are created runtime, are not FBX or any pre-existing 3D model.
I have created 3D shapes in:

1. Unity3D
2. Python
3. ThreeJS

Examples:

ThreeJS

[image]

Unity3D
[image]

Python

[image]

These shapes are not FBX shapes, are just created run-time. Now my targetted output is to display some realistic looking screenshots. I have a room model and I will set these shapes somewhere inside room.
Then I just want to transfer these shapes to any tool and get realistic screenshots. Any tool that can do it is okay for me.

Target output examples:

[image]
[image]

Any tool that can do it is okay for me. I just need solution.

Comment: I think it was somehow possible, for example here https://youtu.be/iuFf-KMojFQ